# to get links from ok.ru web taking search query from excel file using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am unable to get multiple video links from ok.ru using code below :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import openpyxl
 
# Set up Chrome options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
 
# Set up Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
 
# Navigate to ok.ru
driver.get('https://ok.ru')
 
# Accept cookies
# cookies_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#hook_Block_CookieNotifier button.cookie-settings__submit')
# cookies_button.click()
 
# Log in
username_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="st.email"]')
password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="st.password"]')
login_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.button-pro[type="submit"]')
 
username_input.send_keys('user@gmail.com')
password_input.send_keys('Password')
login_button.click()
 
# Read data from input file
input_file = 'input_file.xlsx'
output_file = 'ok_links.xlsx'
 
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_file)
worksheet = workbook.active
max_row = worksheet.max_row
 
# Set up output file
output_workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
output_worksheet = output_workbook.active
 
# Iterate over rows in input file
for row in range(1, max_row + 1):
    query = worksheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value
 
    if query is not None:
        print(f"Searching for {query}")
        search_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="st.query"]')
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys(query)
        search_box.submit()
 
        # Extract the video search results
        video_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hook_Block_SearchMRB"]/portal-search/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h2')
        print(f"Found {len(video_links)} Total Videos")
 
        # Add the video search results to the results sheet
        for link in video_links:
            title_element = link.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hook_Block_SearchMRB"]/portal-search/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h2')
            title = title_element.text
            url = link.get_attribute("href")
            output_worksheet.append([query, title, url])
            print(f"Added link: {title} ({url})")
 
# Save output file
output_workbook.save(output_file)
 
# Clean up
driver.quit()
```

It is working fine for a single link, but I want to grab all links under the search results.

I believe I may have placed the wrong xpath. Any help I can get to resolve this issue is very much appreciated.

Comment: what python script?

Comment: i am not able to paste the script here.

Comment: you're sure able to. You can edit the question and paste the code like you wrote the description. Use ctrl c ctrl v :) then just surround the code with "`" marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of `title_element` you are using `link.find_element` since you want to restrict the search inside `link`. But this is not enough, you also have to add a dot `.` in front of the xpath:

```
.//*[@id="hook_Block_SearchMRB"]/portal-search/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h2
```

Remember

- `//div` finds divs in all the html
- `.//div` finds divs which are descendants of the current node

Moreover

- `.//` finds the descendants of the current node
- `./`  finds the direct children of the current node